# Why do I sometimes need to include "self" as an argument when defining functions in external Python modules?

Tags: python, python-module

Say I have two Python functions defined in a module called `funcs.py`:

```py
def my_fun1(X):
    return X * 2


def my_fun2(X):
    return X / 2
```

and a dataclass defined in a file called `testclass.py`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import funcs


@dataclass
class TestClass:
    MY_FUN = funcs.my_fun1
    MY_FUNS = [funcs.my_fun1, funcs.my_fun2]
    N_X = [3, 4]
```

If I then run some test code:

```py
import numpy as np
from testclass import TestClass

tc = TestClass()

data = [np.random.randn(x, 2) for x in tc.N_X]

print(tc.MY_FUN(data[0]))
```

it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: my_fun1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

If I then change the definition of `my_fun1` to:

```py
def my_fun1(self, X):
```

It works fine, but when I try:

```py
print(tc.MY_FUNS[0](data[0]))
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: my_fun1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

I can get around this by removing the `self` from the definitions and declaring a single function in the test class as a singleton list, e.g., `MY_FUN = [funcs.my_fun1]`, however this feels like a bit of a "hacky" work-around, and I would like to be able to declare either a single function or list of functions without having to change the function definitions down the track.

Is there any way of doing this? Why does Python need the `self` argument sometimes, and not others in this instance?

Comment: The answer is basically "because you moved the functions into a class". Why did you create a class?

Comment: Any attributes that exist on the class which are functions become bound instance methods and receive a `self` argument. It doesn't matter how those functions were defined. A list of functions is not *a function*, so is *not* bound.

Comment: @deceze: okay, so if the functions are independent of that dataclass, then they should just always be defined as a list of functions so they arent bound (even if the size of that list is 0)?

Comment: Alternatively: `MY_FUN = staticmethod(funcs.my_fun1)`

Comment: @mkrieger1: this is just an MWE, in reality, the dataclass contains all of the parameters and settings that define a problem instance, and I am using it like a struct in C, so that it is much easier to pass many variables at the one time